# Diagnosing bad RAM

Tags: memory, bsod

I'm trying to diagnose the problem with an unstable HP Pavillion DV4 with 4 GB of RAM. I'm getting BSODs and several errors trying to install software, etc.

I've tried running memtest86 3.5 off a CD - it hangs up almost immediately, at 46% of test #1, with a message saying "Relocated". I haven't been able to find out what does it mean. memtest 3.4 seems to work OK, though.

This notebook is new (so it says the supplier) but I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with it. It came with Windows7 64bit installed - not sure how stable is it on a dual core Turion, but I guess it should work.

Any suggestions? I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: The subject of this post would be better fitting for poweruser.

Comment: Otherwise known as superuser.com?

Comment: Sorry about that - I figured hardware issues were OK here.

Answer (score 4):

Remove all but one of the RAM modules then run Memtest.  If it tests good then swap it for another RAM module and memtest again. Do this until you find the RAM module that's causing trouble. Then RMA the memory or just leave it out.

If the notebook is new it might come with a warranty and you may consider calling the OEM to have them replace the bad memory under warranty.